# Use matrix multiplication to apply weights to multiple groups

Tags: r

I have a dataset with a series of stores and customer data. I'm trying to segment my analysis using age and sex variables. I'd like to review store sales adjusted by age and sex.

I'm able to calculate the reference weights for the age and sex combinations (`ref_wt`). What I would like to do is then apply those weights to each store.

First, how can I improve the use of a matrix when applying weights? Second, how do I account for stores that may not have a customer group when building each matrix? For example, a store with only males?

My goal is to multiple `ref_wt` by each stores cross-tab of customers.

**Edit** my question may break down to proper approach if anything. What benefits do I get from the matrix structure over, say, using `group_by` and joins?

```
> dat <- as.data.frame(list(sex = c('m', 'm', 'f', 'm', 'f'),
                            under_30 = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
                            paid = c(0, 10, 3, 5, 20)))
> 
> # calc avg overall
> ref_total <- mean(dat$paid)
> ref_total
[1] 7.6
> 
> # calc avg by segment
> ref_seg <-  dat %>% 
    group_by(sex, under_30) %>% 
    summarise(x = mean(paid)) %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>% 
    spread(., sex, x) %>% 
    replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
    as.data.frame.matrix()
>ref_seg
  under_30  f   m
1        0 20 7.5
2        1  3 0.0

># drop under_30 row name
>ref_seg <- ref_seg[,2:3]
>ref_seg
   f   m
1 20 7.5
2  3 0.0
>
># calc seg weights
>ref_wt <- ref_seg / ref_total
>ref_wt
          f         m
1 2.6315789 0.9868421
2 0.3947368 0.0000000
```

Comment: Would you edit your code removing the time-stamped cursors? It makes it hard to read and much harder to copy/paste/run. Adding comment characters to the start of output lines would be nice too, to make it easy for people to see what's going on  and experiment.

Comment: But to address the general question, matrix operations *should* be more efficient than data frame operations. If that matters to you, use them; if not, don't.